# Keeping track of callbacks and sending the data out as a single array

Tags: javascript, callback

I have a script that loops through each element and loops through each attribute of that element. If the element's attribute name matches a key name in a separate object (`shims`) it runs a JS shim. The JS shim then adds to an array (errors). After *all* the shims (if any shims even ran) have returned data sent as a single array i.e.

`<input data-foobar="true">`

and

```
shims:{
 'data-foobar':function(){
    //AJAX stuff...
    if(there_was_an_error){
      errors.push({element:ele,error:'OH NOES!'})
    }
  }
}
```

I'm having a tough time wrapping my head around keeping track of all these since they are all ran milliseconds apart but, obviously, could take longer to return being that these are AJAX calls to a DB.

The only way i can think of is to increase a counter like "`shimsRunning++`" and then having a check `if(shimsRunning === 0){ callback(this,errors) }`. Is that really the best way to do this? Seems kludgy to keep a counter of callbacks waiting a response tho...

Oh, FYI, these are all ran on hitting a button (submit). And i need to wait until these all respond so I know if there were errors, and if so what were they on what and if none, let the form be submitted.

Comment: the kludge you speak of is common practice in node.js. its how most of the fork-join loops work.

Comment: OK, thanks. I was just making sure i wasn't missing a design pattern that'd make this cleaner

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a nice flow control library.

https://github.com/caolan/async is a popular (and good) one.

```
var asyncTasks = ["a", "b"]

function runTask (task, done) {
    somethingAsync(function (err) {
        done(err)
    })
}

async.forEachSeries(asyncTasks, runTask, function (err) {
    // runs when all tasks are done
    // if one of them calls done with an error,
    //   this will be called right away with that error
})
```

That will run things runTask in order (it will run the next one when the previous one finishes).  If you want to run them in parallel check out async.forEach.  If you want to run x in parallel check out async.forEachLimit.